# Optimize multi if-else condition with String.endwith?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Is there a solution for optimization about this code or can convert to switch-case ?

```
if (str.endsWith("a")){
   methodA(str);
}
else if (str.endsWith("bc")){
   methodB(str);
}
else if (str.endsWith("cs")){
   methodC(str);
}
else if (str.endsWith("dsgsgd")){
   methodD(str);
}
```

Comment: can use`regex` but it won't be optimized

Comment: I don't see a way to use a switch statement with this logic. A lot of the "optimizations" we could suggest would depend on what is being done inside of the `if`s and `else if`s. Could you provide that?

Comment: Don't "optimize" unless you know you have a bottleneck.  Chances are this code isn't going to be a bottleneck, and you won't know until you profile it.  I would complete ignore this unless you have data showing it's a problem.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil - I forgot the name of the person who said that

Comment: i edited the code inside `if else`, it will call method with same parameter is `str`

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? You may use switch case with String in Java

Comment: @JavaHopper how to in this case? I am using java 8

Comment: What do you mean by optimize? For speed, or readability, or something else?

Comment: for readability because i have many `if-else` like this